# How to get cron name which calls my function

Tags: wp-mail, cron

I need to send to users who have birthdays an email with a coupon, and I don't want the emails to be sent in very quick succession. I want to send them in 1 second intervals.

I implemented the idea of sending email async according https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185296/218153 and overwrote the pluggable function `wp_mail`, which works great if `wp_mail` is not called by a cron. But I need to call it by a cron. How to get the cron name which called the function and allow to skip the condition `if ( ! defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) || ( defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) && ! DOING_CRON ) )` and not do that for cron *cron_send_mail* from the code above, which basically reschedules the sending of emails?
Thanks for an idea.